# PrimeNg paginator wont display "Entries per page" or Showing entries per page

Tags: angular, pagination, primeng, paginator

I don't want to use paginator=true, because (on Page Change)="paginate($event)" wont work with that. How can fix that part. On the left side I want it to show "entries per page 1to5 of 100" or "showing entries per page" something like that. It is not allowing me to copy and paste code. I'm using a P table for my data table.

Below is in my TS file. total Records: number;  first = 0; rows = 5;

HTML :

```
<p-table \[value\] = "my data"
\[rows\] = "rows"\[first\] = "first"
(on Page) = "paginate($event)"\[columns\] = "table Column"\[auto Layout\] = "true"
\[table Style\] = "{'min-width': '55rem'}"\[scrollable\] = "true" scroll Height = "700px"
current Page Report Template = "Showing {first} to {last} of {total Records} entries" \>

<p-paginator aria-label="pagination" [total Records]="total Records" [rows]="rows" [first]="first"
        (on Page Change)="paginate($event)">
    </p-paginator>


Note: Plz ignore spaces between words in code as it is not allowing me to paste the code.
```